# Is there a Share library like this one out there? for React native

Tags: react-native

I have been seeing this Share library in many new Apps and I was wondering if there is one like it already. if not, how does one trigger opening WhatsApp and Facebook in React Native? thank you[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import { Share} from 'react-native'`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Share, View, Button } from 'react-native';

const ShareExample = () => {
  const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      });
      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <Button onPress={onShare} title="Share" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ShareExample;
```

or
`react-native-share` library
`npm i react-native-share --save` to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `Linking.openURL` and `social_icon` together

(A) For social icons, you may install and use by referring to this **official link**:

```
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/social_icon/
```

(B) For opening social media / email, etc thru Linking.openURL, the following are some examples:

```
Linking.openURL('fb://page/PAGE_ID');
Linking.openURL('http://instagram.com/_u/USER_NAME');
Linking.openURL('http://instagram.com/_p/PICTURE');
Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com')
```

Note: you have to **import Linking** , such as follows:

```
import { Button, Linking, View } from 'react-native';
```